# white border depending of size of the image

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I want to make a ImageView of specyfic height (1/3 of the screen) with white border and the image will be resize according to the height (to keep the proportion) for example. It will be perfect if also I will be able to add TextView below the image. I want to obtain smth like that :

[image]

```
  <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="3"
android:background="@color/backgroundContent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
   >
    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/pic"
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="5dp"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressPic"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

edit: Im downloading images form url using Glide library if that matter

Comment: Try setting the height programmatically by calculating screen size.